# jackson serialization of nested objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have problem with jackson serialization of object by its interface.

I have class

```
class Point implements PointView {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Point() {

    }

    public Point(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

which implements

```
interface PointView {
    String getId();
}
```

and have class

```
class Map implements MapView {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Point point;

    public Map() {

    }

    public Map(String id, String name, Point point) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.point = point;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(as = PointView.class)
    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

}
```

which implements

```
interface MapView {
    String getId();
    Point getPoint();
}
```

And have class

```
class Container {

    private Map map;

    public Container() {

    }

    public Container(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(as = MapView.class)
    public Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

I want serialize Container with Jackson and get result

```
{"map":{"id":"mapId","point":{"id":"pointId"}}}
```

But in fact I get result

```
{"map":{"id":"mapId","point":{"id":"pointId","name":"pointName"}}}
```

that have property "name" in nested object "point" although I specified serializition type of Point in Map (`@JsonSerialize(as = PointView.class)`). Interface PointView dont have method getName, but in result exists field "name" of Point.

If I remove annotation (`@JsonSerialize(as = MapView.class)`) from method getMap in class Container I get result

```
{"map":{"id":"mapId","name":"mapName","point":{"id":"pointId"}}}
```

Now point dont have property "name", but map have.

How can I get result

```
{"map":{"id":"mapId","point":{"id":"pointId"}}}
```

?

Comment: I found solution of this problem. Annotation @JsonSerialize also must be setted in interface `interface MapView { String getId(); @JsonSerialize(as = PointView.class) Point getPoint(); }`

Comment: Best: You write your solution as an answer and tick is as correct. (As soon as it is possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the desired result also the same method in interface must be annotated by `@JsonSerialize`

```
interface MapView {
    String getId();
    @JsonSerialize(as = PointView.class)
    Point getPoint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the method like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Or if you want specific serialization in this use case, but normal serialization in others, you can use a `@JsonView` (see [doc](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)).

The reason it's serializing out the `name` is that the *instance* has the accessor `getName()`, even though interface does not.

Comment: Yes. `@JsonIgnore` works. But class Point may be part of other class, which serialization must contain the "name" property of Point. I want specify serilization of class only by its interface. Is it possible?

Comment: There are problem with `@JsonView`. If class `Point` will have several other nested objects and each nested object will have their nested objects. With `@JsonView` I must set this annotation to all nested objects to include they in serialization. it is not nice considering that the chain of nested objects can be very large. I want that each class may set serialization view each nested objects

Comment: You could make a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of the object and null the name field of its Point object.

Comment: Yes. deep copy may help. But I dont want write additional code for deep copy. I search nice solution of this problem

Comment: Bohemian, thanks for you help. I found solution of this problem. Annotation `@JsonSerialize` also must be setted in interface  
 `interface MapView {
  String getId();
  @JsonSerialize(as = PointView.class)
  Point getPoint();
 }`

Comment: @anar you should post your solution as an answer to your own question (it's perfectly OK to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
@JsonSerialize(as=MyInterface.class)
public class ConcreteClass implements MyInterface { .... }
```

either on implementation class (as above), or on property that has value.