# How can I change class name during serialization using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

'us.package.high.MyClass' is not in the trusted packages:
java.util, java.lang,us.package.low.MyClass

Classes are identical. How can I change typeId (Class name) during serialization?
Now it's 'us.package.high.MyClass', but I need make it just 'MyClass';

Comment: Could you show some example what do you get right now and what would you like to receive?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation of Jackson :

```
package us.package.high.MyClass;

@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)
public class MyClass {

...

}
```

If you are using Jackson to handle JSON, it will help.

If you are using another library, search about that feature.

If you are using no library to handle JSON, try to implement a `toString()` method and in fact implements the `Serializable` interface :

```
public  class MyClass  implements Serializable { \\... }
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't help

Comment: Update : If you are using Jackson to handle JSON, it will help.
If you are using another library, search about that feature.
If you are using no library to handle JSON, try to implement a Serializable method or implements the `Serializable` interface : `public  class MyClass  implements Serializable { \\... }

Comment: Look at these post on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151974/390462